# El paquete de instalcion no es compatible con este procesador en mongo db

Tags: mongodb

este es el mensaje que me sale cuando quiero instalar MongoDb en mi laptop que es una Lenovo I3 de 3gb de ram he buscado en youtube y los pocos pasos que dan lo he hecho y no obtenido solucion si alguien sabe que puede estar ocurriendo mi sistema es de 32bits con procesador de 64bits

---

Lamentablemente no me funciono tenia las esperanzas pero nada este es mi sistema operativo no se que pueda estar pasando [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cualquier comentario debes hacerlo aquí en esta sección debajo de tu propie publicación; y si quieres agregar código (preferiblemente), imágenes o algún contenido adicional debes usar el botón de editar tu propio post

Comment: La solución inmediata es instalar un S.O. acorde al procesador que tienes. Si tienes un procesador Core i3, lo lógico es usar un S.O. de 64 bits. Tal como dice la respuesta proporcionada por @FranciscoNúñez, no podrás instalar una versión superior a 3.2 de MongoDB en un sistema de 32 bits. Y dado que esa versión ya es antigua, tal vez no tenga soporte para Windows 10. Por lo tanto veo difícil una solución a tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que estas tratando de instalar la ultima version; MongoDB no tiene soporte en S.O 32 bits:

[Documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms)

> **Supported Platforms**: 
> Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB no longer supports 32-bit x86 platforms.

Tendrías que usar la version 3.2.22; verificas si estos paquetes te sirve ya que no tengo S.O de 32 bits para hacer pruebas:

[Link MSI](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.22-signed.msi)

[Link Zip](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.22.zip)

**Técnicamente la solución es que trabajes con un S.O soportado por el software, en su version más actual.**